java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter
I am trying to migrate spring boot from 1.5.22.RELEASE to 2.0.9.RELEASE and while running the server getting error
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter at   jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[?:?]at  
jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]at  java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:?]at  java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[?:?]at  java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[?:?]at  org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]

my pom.xml looks like this
<properties>
    <jacoco-plugin.version>0.8.5</jacoco-plugin.version>
    <cxf.version>3.3.10</cxf.version>
    <commons-logging.version>1.2</commons-logging.version>
    <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.8.1</commons-lang3.version>

    <java.version>11</java.version>

    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <jackson.version>2.9.8</jackson.version>
    <log4j.version>2.17.2</log4j.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.2</surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-war-plugin.version>3.2.3</maven-war-plugin.version>
    <!-- <spring-boot.version>1.5.22.RELEASE</spring-boot.version> -->
    <spring-boot.version>2.0.9.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <swagger.version>1.5.24</swagger.version>
    <swagger-ui.version>3.20.9</swagger-ui.version>
    <serenity.version>2.0.82</serenity.version>
    <hystrix.version>1.5.18</hystrix.version>
    <hikaricp.version>3.4.1</hikaricp.version>
    <mariadb-java-client.version>2.5.1</mariadb-java-client.version>
    <jaxws-api.version>2.3.2</jaxws-api.version>
    <powermock.version>2.0.4</powermock.version>
    <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
    <spring-ws.version>2.4.6.RELEASE</spring-ws.version>

</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Testing -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Added for Java upgrade -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
        <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

I also found that class - ErrorPageFilter is available in package org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support in upgraded spring-boot version 2.0.9.RELEASE but my code is still looking in org.springframework.boot.web.support
Also getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcProperties
where class WebMvcProperties is available in package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet in upgraded spring-boot version
After upgradation I fixed all compilation issues and local build is successful with skipping test cases, getting this error's while running any test's or starting the server
Any help on finding why the code is still looking into previous package instead of new package, Thanks

This question is similar to: org.springframework.boot.web.support does not exist. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The solution provided here is to use org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer which is already implemented in my code, also my local build is getting successful while skipping test cases. While trying to run test cases or start server I am getting the mentioned error's, the solution provided in this question is not helpful to me
